# How to check the accuracy of smartphone sensor

Tags: android, android-sensors

My task is to measure and check the accuracy of the orientation sensor in a smartphone and proof it.

I know that there are different apps to get the data from the smartphone, but how can I check whether the data is accurate or not?

Comment: Refer to this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

Comment: yes exactly, i have already read that and programmed an app that displays the data of the sensors on the screen... that was the first part of my project, but now i have to check whether the data is correct or not and how accurate is it.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038232/how-to-check-accuracy-values-on-onaccuracychanged-method-in-sensor-event-listeni/42910278#42910278