# How to use onAccuracyChanged function in sensors

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

I am making an app in which am using two sensors.

1. `TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`
2. `TYPE_GRAVITY`

I initialized the respective sensors and then in `onSensorChanged` function, am fetching the data and doing the calculations on the same.

I have one simple question, how can I use `onAccuracyChanged` function to filter out data? I want the data with medium and high accuracy!!

I printed basic statements to see what kind of accuracy am getting while debugging the app.

**Code :**

```
`@Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
        // You must implement this callback in your code.
        //  I initialized mValuen as mValuen = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

        if (sensor == mValuen) {
            switch (accuracy) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Unreliable");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Low Accuracy");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Medium Accuracy");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("High Accuracy");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }`
```

As per my understanding, whenever a sensor reports a new value `onSensorChanged` function is called. So I can't really call that function explicitly(Even if I could,that will anyway be called upon whenever the sensor reports a new value).

All of my calculations are in that function. How do I filter out data with medium and high accuracy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34292918/3538065) answer of mine for more elaborated answer.

Let's say this is the `onAccurayChanged` function.

```
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
        // You must implement this callback in your code.
        if (sensor == mValuen) {
            switch (accuracy) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Unreliable");
                    con=0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Low Accuracy");
                    con=0;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Medium Accuracy");
                    con=1;

                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("High Accuracy");
                    con=1;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I declared a global variable and kept it as 0.
And in the `onSensorChanged` function, where am doing the required calculations, am putting an `if..else` condition. If the `con` value is 1, then only am doing the calculations. 
Am getting the output. But please let me know if my approach is wrong in some way or other. 
Thanks.