# Working on Pedometer, MainActivity Class Not Compiling

Tags: java, android

I found a Pedometer tutorial that I wanted to try. Everything works fine except the very first part. This is the link to the tutorial. http://blog.bawa.com/2013/11/create-your-own-simple-pedometer.html

here is my code -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private TextView textView;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mStepCounterSensor;
private Sensor mStepDetectorSensor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)
            getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    mStepDetectorSensor = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
}

//sensoreventlistener method
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
    float[] values = event.values;
    int value = -1;

    if (values.length > 0) {
        value = (int) values[0];
    }

    if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
        textView.setText("Step Counter Detected : " + value);
    } else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {

        textView.setText("Step Detector Detected : " + value);
    }
}

protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCounterSensor,

            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor,

            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepCounterSensor);
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor);
}
}
```

I am still getting better at debugging but not quite yet. This is a picture of my issue.

[image]

I always get similar issues like this that end up stalling my progress. Any advice would be appreciated. I know its a simple fix that I can't quite see yet.

Comment: Looks like you need to add `onAccuracyChanged(Sensor, int)` to your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include and override method onAccuracyChanged. This link may be of assistance [How to use onAccuracyChanged function in sensors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273681/how-to-use-onaccuracychanged-function-in-sensors)